# How to set default length on all fields in entity framework fluent api?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Is it possible to set default length of all string fields (unless I say otherwise)? 
At the moment it really bugs me to go and add something like

`modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().Property(x => x.YardLine).HasMaxLength(256);`
to each and every string field, just to avoid having nvarchar(max) on all my strings columns in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something called [Custom Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx), but only if you're using Entity Framework 6+.

As @ranquild [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30874475/4812586), you can use

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(256));
```

to configure the default maximum length for all string properties. You can even filter which properties to apply your configuration to:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
    .Where(p => someCondition)
    .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(256));
```

Finally, any configuration on the entity type itself would take precedence. For example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>().Property(x => x.StringProperty)
    .HasMaxLength(DifferentMaxLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(256));
```